# How to fix encoding issues in Python

Tags: python, encoding

This code throws some encoding error:

```
import re
import os

resume = re.sub(r'ââ‚¬â€œ', '', 'ââ‚¬â€œ')
resume = re.sub(r'ïâ€š§', '', 'ïâ€š§')
resume = re.sub(r'ïÂ® ', '', 'ïÂ® ')
print resume
```

Error:

```
File "script.py", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file script.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: It says "see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details". Did you do that?

Comment: Add ´# coding=<encoding name>´ on the first line.

Comment: no encoding declared. So declare an encoding.

Comment: i added all encodings but nothing works

Comment: Bigger picture question: why are you trying to `sub` garbage in the first place…?

Comment: if i use those lines the script throws error even if i comment out those lines deceze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying here with re.sub,

```
re.sub(r'ââ‚¬â€œ', '', 'ââ‚¬â€œ')
```

But to run the code in your case, just add this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys

resume = re.sub(r'ââ‚¬â€œ', '', 'ââ‚¬â€œ')
resume = re.sub(r'ïâ€š§', '', 'ïâ€š§')
resume = re.sub(r'ïÂ® ', '', 'ïÂ® ')
print resume
```

This won't give you any error nor any output, so change re.sub in this way.

```
resume = re.sub(ur'ââ‚¬â€œ', '', 'ââ‚¬â€œ')
```

If you're using 2.x, try making the regex string a Unicode-escape string, with 'u'. Since it's regex it's good practice to make your regex string a raw string, with 'r'.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a Unicode string by adding a prefix `u`:

```
import re
import os

import re
import os

resume = re.sub(ur'ââ‚¬â€œ', '', u'ââ‚¬â€œ')
print resume
resume = re.sub(ur'ïâ€š§', '', u'ïâ€š§')
print resume
resume = re.sub(ur'ïÂ® ', '', u'ïÂ® ')
print resume
```

Outputs empty strings.

Or convert it to Unicode and then replace if the values are in variables:

```
import re
import os

s1 = 'ââ‚¬â€œ'
s2 = 'ïâ€š§'
s3 = 'ïÂ® '
resume = re.sub(ur'ââ‚¬â€œ', '', unicode(s1))
print resume
resume = re.sub(ur'ïâ€š§', '', unicode(s2))
print resume
resume = re.sub(ur'ïÂ® ', '', unicode(s3))
print resume
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell Python how to decode your text:

`#! coding: utf-8`

... your code here ...

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
unicode(<?add your value here>).encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: An example will be encouraged i tried this but still not working unicode(<?"ââ‚¬â€œ">).encode("utf-8")

Answer (score -1):

Also you can add this line at first line of the **.py** file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```